SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storePassword" evne though it exists
I'm trying to build a release apk from my Flutter project, as you can see in .gradle file the keys are being accessed by System.getenv(name), here is my portion of the build.gradle file responsible for that:
 release {
            keyAlias 'e-commerce-alias'
            keyPassword System.getenv("KEYPASSWORD")
            storePassword System.getenv("STOREPASSWORD")
            storeFile file("e-commerce.keystore")
        }

here is my .bashrc files:
export KEYPASSWORD="****"
export STOREPASSWORD="****"
export KEY_STORE_PATH="/home/omer358/Documents/keystore_files/e-commerce-releasa.keystore"

when I tried to build a release APK with the above configurations I got the error indicating that the SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storePassword". , the weird thing is the mentioned property does exist! when I tried to hard-code the properties, unexpectedly, everything works just fine! the APK is successfully built and installed!
this behavior happens both on my local and my CI "GITHUB ACTIONS",
here is how  I added the environment variables in local and my repo:
Local:

I added the variables in my .bashrc file in my Linux environment as they appear above.
I run source ~/.bashrc

Github:

I added my properties as secrets in my repo.
In my build.yaml file I made a step to access the secrets and add them to `GITHUB_ENV

 # Set environment variables
      - name: Set environment variables
        run: |
          echo "export KEYPASSWORD=${{ secrets.E_COMMERCE_KEY_PASSWORD }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "export STOREPASSWORD=${{ secrets.E_COMMERCE_STORE_PASSWORD }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

again, everything works fine in both environment when I hard-code the keyPassword and storePassword!

EDIT
In my local when I run echo $STOREPASSWORD it does print the value, so, the problem is not with my environment variable!

Please dont expose your key passwords, you should probably create a new one now since it can be viewed

no worries, those are just for demonstration, but thanks for the hits

The bottom line is:
You can't run a release using this way. It’s a good practice to separate sensitive information like keypassword and storepassword using methods like flutter_dotenv or System.getenv, etc...
This methods created to helps us manage files.
More explain:
First if you are using flutter_dotenv, System.getenv or any way to seperate the keypassword, storepassword or any secret file, its good and we're often  use it when we use flavor to manage files, or to prevent uploading secrets files into VCS (also we can use .gitignore). However when you run flutter build apk, the complier will create the apk file and you can install it, because you don't yet configured the project for release and even though you can create appbundle. but if you have configured the project to release, like creating an upload keystore and configure signing in gradle, etc..
In this case you will be able to create .apk file, but you can't create a release, because the keypasswod and keystore will be required for signing process and you have to use the recommended way at documentation, not System.getenv becuase this way as i mentioned before for managing files.
